# polish characters in the file, include function - sas

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have a problem with include function in Enterprise Guide, I have a polish e-mail there, but instead of polish characters I just see �
If I don't use the include function and I have the e-mail directly in the sas program - is ok, when I do it global is not.

My code:

```
filename genericq ('.' '/abc/cde/) encoding="utf-8";
%include genericq('generic.sas');
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: What language is your SAS install running in?  ("UTF-8" is a language, as is "English")

Comment: But I don't understand why until I use include function I have polish characters in my e-mail but when in the separate file I define just macros variables and I use %include function for the rest (I have that in seperate file .sas), I am losing polish characters. Is there something wrong with file encoding?

Comment: Because SAS-handling-UTF-8 characters in *code* is different from handling characters in *data*.  To have them in *code* you have to be running SAS in UTF-8 mode.

Comment: I changed the encoding of the file to UTF-8, my mistake, thank you :)